# Shuffling questions in only one section of a Google Form

Tags: google-forms

I am creating this Google Form with two sections. One takes the student information; Reg. No., Name, Class etc., and the other section contains the subject-related questions which I need to have shuffled every time a student login. How can I accomplish this task? I.e., have the first set of student information not shuffled while the questions get shuffled. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user eight times.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

As of October 2023, the form is the Google Forms setting to shuffle question order scope. I can't be set to shuffle only the questions of a specific section or to set an exception to avoid shuffling the questions of a specific question.

For your convenience, I'm copying below an extract of the help article [Edit your form](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2839737?hl=en), more specifically the section **Randomly order questions and answers** > **Shuffle question order**

> ##### Shuffle question order
>
> **Important:** If you want your questions to appear in a specific order, you should not shuffle your questions.
>
> 1. At the top of the form, click Settings.
> 2. Next to “Presentation,” click the Down arrow Down arrow.
> 3. Under “Form presentation,” turn on Shuffle question order.

Google Apps Script and Google Forms API can't be used for this because they might be used only on the server side, not on the client side of the form view, either when the form is opened by a viewer or after it is loaded.